# Tomcat bootstrap behavior

Tags: java, tomcat, sdk, liferay, portlet

I have a tomcat server that boots up and runs customized webapps. I've updated some supporting sdk's and tried updating said SDK's. It's obviously unzipping a web archive file somewhere and I can't for the life of me find that .war file. If I delete the tomcat/work and tomcat/temp folders, "replace" the old webapp/portlet-folder-name/WEB-INF/lib with a new lib folder that has my new SDK's only and start up the server again. Once I go back to webapp/portlet-folder-name/WEB-INF/lib.. It has my new SKD's and the old ones too.

It's driving me bonkers because I know I need to update the SDK's in the .war file. But I can't find where the heck the .war file is. I've looked in every directory in the server. Is there some kind of way that would allow me to find out how and where that server is unpacking that archived file/or folder? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You tag Liferay, which does (in versions 7.x) no longer deploy webapps to tomcat, but to its internal OSGi runtime.

You can use gogo shell to uninstall, or just redeploy the updated plugins again (through Liferay's `deploy` directory)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! It was running Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2 CE GA2. Would you know anything with regard to that version? This was an old legacy app and I'm trying to work with technology I understand very little about. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!